# ODE with time-varying coefficients in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode

I am evaluating a set of ODEs with time varying coefficients

```
def deriv(y, t, N, coefficients):
    S, I, R = y
    dSdt = coefficients['beta'](t) * S * I / N * -1
    dIdt = coefficients['beta'](t) * S * I / N - coefficients['gamma']* I
    dRdt = coefficients['gamma'] * I
    return dSdt, dIdt, dRdt
```

In particular, I have 'beta' values in a pre-calculated array, of size equal to int(max(t)).

```
coefficients = {'beta' : beta_f,'gamma':0.1}
def beta_f(t):
     return  mybetas.iloc[int(t)]

# Initial conditions vector
y0 = (S0, I0, R0)
# Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
ret = odeint(deriv,y0,t,args=(N,coefficients))
```

When I run odeint, it is evaluate also for value beyond max(t), raising an index out of bound error in beta_f.
How to limit the evaluation span for odeint?

Answer (score 2):

Since `len(mybetas) == int(max(t))`, you can get an out-of-bounds error even for values of t which are not beyond max(t).
For example, `mybetas.iloc[int(max(t))]` will give you the out-of-bounds error, even though `int(max(t)) <= max(t)` for positive values of `t`.

But to your point, `odeint` does indeed check some values outside of the domain of integration. I had to deal with a problem similar to yours just a few weeks ago, and the following two discussions on stackoverflow were really helpful:

[integrate.ode sets t0 values outside of my data range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25031966)

[Solve ODEs with discontinuous input/forcing data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32225472)

The second link explains why it might be computationally faster to solve the ODE with `odeint` over each individual integer time step one after the other in a `for` loop, instead of letting `odeint` deal with the discontinuities in your derivative caused by jumps in the values of your betas.

Otherwise, if this is appropriate for your study case, you can interpolate your betas, and let the function `beta_f` return interpolated values of beta. Of course, you will have to extend the interpolation domain slightly beyond your integration domain, since `odeint` might want to evaluate the derivative for some `t` larger than `max(t)`.